# In a Visual Studio 2022 Node.js project is there a way to publish all files in the "dist" folder

Tags: node.js, webpack, visual-studio-2022

In a Visual Studio 2022 Node.js project, is there a way to publish all files in the "dist" folder to our webserver?  I would like to add some code to the Visual Studio project file (.njsproj) to force all files to be copied to our webserver even if they are not "included" in the VS project.

The reason for this is that when I compile and bundle the project typescript files, the bundle chunk file names in the "dist" folder change depending on if it is bundled for "production" or "development".  I am using WebPack and ESBuild for the bundling.

Comment: Isn't that something you should make your CI/CD do? Push the changes to your version control, have your CI/CD pick up on that change and build-and-push production _if_ tests pass.